# Proving eigenvalues are real and nonpositive

Tags: linear-algebra

If a matrix $L$ can be written as $L = P^{-1}Q$ where $PL = L^{T}P$, and $P$ is a diagonal matrix and $Q$ is symmetric, how can I show that $L$ has all real and nonpositive eigenvalues?

I also know every entry on the diagonal matrix is positive, if that helps.

I tried left multiplying the equation for $PL$ with the inverse of $P$ but got nowhere. Maybe that assumption is not needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $PL = Q$ so for any eigenvector of $L$ we have:
\begin{align}
PLv = P\lambda v = Qv \rightarrow \lambda v^{*}Pv = v^{*}Qv
\end{align}
We know that the Matrix $P$ is symmetric and positive definite (because of the positive entries) therefore the LHS is always positive and we know that the Matrix Q is symmetric and Hermitian so the RHS is always A Real number therefore $\lambda$ has to be Real.

There is no need for $\lambda$ to be nonnegative for example take:
\begin{align}
P = I,   Q = \begin{bmatrix}
1 \hspace{0.7 cm}0\\
0 \hspace{0.1 cm} -1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
and we have $L = Q$ but the eigenvalues of $L$ Are $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that I want to show the eigenvalues are _nonpositive_, not _nonnegative_. Do you know how I might do this?

Comment: The example I gave shows that L can have both negative and positive eigenvalues. You can put whatever numbers you want on the main diagonal of the matrix Q defined above and those will be your eigenvalues.